# Squid ACL rules files are not working on Windows

Tags: windows, web, acl, blocking, squid

I use a Windows server to host [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) and loaded some [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) rules from file to block ads. The file is loaded, but the ACL rules don't work, and I can still access the web page which is located in the file. How can I fix it?

These are my blocking rules:

```
#Block ads start
acl ads_host dstdom_regex "c:/squid/etc/ad_block_host.txt"
acl ads_ip dst "c:/squid/etc/ad_block_ip.txt"
http_access deny ads_host
http_access deny ads_ip
#Block ads end
```

Comment: Could you try with `dstdomain`, as in https://workaround.org/squid-acls?

Comment: I have try `dstdomain` also but fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `URL_REGEX`. Only that worked for me in Windows.

Comment: Sorry can you explain more?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of dstdomain, use `url_regex -i` and make a file with either hostnames. For example, `.facebook.com` or simply `facebook`. One regex per line will work.